# Why is unity so crazy slow?

Tags: unity, 11.10, updates

I updated to 11.10 this week and I've been hitting my head against the wall ever since. I have a two year old Lenovo x301. It shouldn't be "underpowered" but Unity grinds it to a halt.

Memory: 3.8 GiB 
Processor: Intel® Core™2 Duo CPU U9400 @ 1.40GHz × 2

What gives?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to have resolved itself. Weird.

Answer (score 1):

The problem might be your VGA adapter. What is your VGA model and vendor? Or is it an onboard one?

Comment: Not sure how to find that in 11.10. xorg.conf is gone ...

Comment: You could try to get some information on the website. I'll look now, and tell you what I can find.

Comment: Seems I can't find anything usable on the site, I do think that your product does not have Linux drivers. Could you check for restricted drivers? search for "Additional Drivers" in the Dash Home and let it check if there are any drivers for your Notebook.

Comment: It works fine with Gnome, but fails in Unity. It doesn't make sense for this to be about video drivers. However: no, there aren't any proprietary drivers installed.